# Including 2 iframes in one HTML

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to include 2 iframes in an HTML. The issue is, only the content of the first iFrame is displayed and nothing, icluded inside the HTML, after this first iFrame is displayed.What could be causing browser to display the content of first iFrame only?

Comment: Are the iframes inside one another.  If not they should not affect each other unless the first one does not have a closing tag

Comment: If the fist frame is holder of the second and it belong to other domain, it may be taken for XSS (cross site scripting). In order to avoid XSS attacks and phishing most of the browsers deny such requests and require special verification procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be that you are not closing the first iframe tag or you are leaving some quotes open for some parameters in the tag. If you post your code I can give you a better answer.

Good Luck!,
Chris